# Getting INTERNAL SERVER ERROR while using REST API

Tags: java, xml, rest, maven, jersey

Trying to implement REST services using JERSEY project but getting below error:
This is the message I receive in the console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/core/FeatureContext
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache.compute(LRUHybridCache.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl.getAllMethods(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.findInitializerMethods(Utilities.java:1400)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.DefaultClassAnalyzer.getInitializerMethods(DefaultClassAnalyzer.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getInitializerMethods(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:218)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getInitMethods(Utilities.java:196)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justInject(Utilities.java:974)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.inject(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:998)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1073)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1064)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.createAndInitialize(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.createAndInitialize(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:30)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureAutoDiscoverableProviders(CommonConfig.java:592)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.configureAutoDiscoverableProviders(ResourceConfig.java:810)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:322)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$1(ApplicationHandler.java:293)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:347)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1089)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4876)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5185)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
```

Please find the code and xml files.
Thanks in advance

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>restdemo</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>restdemo</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>restdemo</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>3.0.0-M1</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

**Alien.java**

```
 package com.rest.restdemo;
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

 @XmlRootElement 
 public class Alien {   
 private String name;   
 private int points;    
 public String getName() {      
 return name;   
 }  
 public void setName(String name) {         
  this.name = name;     
 }  
 public int getPoints()
 {      
    return points; 
 }  
 public void setPoints(int points) 
 {
        this.points = points;   
 }
}
```

**AlienResource.java**

```
package com.rest.restdemo;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
@Path("aliens")

public class AlienResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Alien getAlien() {

        Alien a=new Alien();
        a.setName("Sam");
        a.setPoints(60);
        return a;
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.rest.restdemo</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When i am launching this on browser i am getting INTERNAL SERVER ERROR-500

Please help me how to handle INTERNAL SERVER ERROR during run time in REST. Am i missing on some dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have jax-rs dependency in your pom?

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: yes i have jax-rs dependency added as jar file but i was still getting the error what worked for me is the jersey version change to 2.29.1, earlier i was using 3.0.0-M1 is it that the version is unstable ?